# What is this texture mask used for and how can I apply it in blender?

Tags: texturing, shaders, image, id-mask

I downloaded a tree model and it came with a diffuse, normal and mask texture maps. Im not sure how this specific mask texture is suppose to be used or how to apply it in blender and I cant find a whole lot of info on it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*It looks like [Cryptomatte](https://lesterbanks.com/2016/07/crytomatte-automatic-id-mattes/) ... that doesn't make a sense for this kind of material. Usually used for compositing.*

More sense makes [**Normal Map**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/normal_map.html) texture, that let branches to appear as angled for light (not as flat plane).

[image]

Just a Normal Map node ...

[image]

Additionaly it can be used as Alpha factor (if you separate R channel), but it doesn't seems to be purpose, since edges are not anti-aliased.

Here could be used also for a color variations, probably?

[image]

[image]
(It works without RGB separation too. You can plug texture directly to ColorRamp node as well.)

Comment: Color variations make sense! It already came with its own normal map separate from this one. How would you apply this to create different color variations?.

Also, thanks for pointing out the lack of anti aliasing. Although this makes it a little more confusing because that's how I was pulling the alpha originally. But if this isn't the purpose for this, Im not sure how else to pull the alpha WITH the anti-aliasing. None of the textures seem to be anti-aliased so does that mean that's how it is in game? The textures were extracted directly from Fortnite on my PC.

Comment: If you pulled this from a game asset, it's likely that they have channel-packed one image with multiple maps to save memory @bonypoy

Comment: Ah I see, so if I’m understanding correctly. For example the Red channel would have roughness, Green would have specular, and Blue would have…an alpha? Maybe that’s where I get confused,  which maps should be packed into what channel?

Comment: @bonypoy correct, I don't know if there's any standard practice, but someone out there surely has the info

Comment: Well thank you so much for your input! It definitely seems to be a channel packed image. Going to be researching more on that!

Comment: I thought it is channel-packed image too (and it can be partly used in that way), but if you check channels, the only ways to use them I see, are mentioned in the answer, but ...R for Alpha is outlined (straight / premultiplied), so if I'm using it right there should be another texture/channel transparency. B looks like a branches separation, but doesn't contains small one upper left. So my guess is still Normal map (Displacement?), Normal map you mentioned is probably for needles plasticity?